# Mini Coupe loses power while accellerating

Tags: power-loss

Hi I have a twin turbo mini coupe and lately it is losing power when I accelerate hard. Usually when my revs are around 4000-5000 RPM. It use to rev to around 7500. I have to back off slightly or change gear. So if I take off in 1st, once it gets to around 4000-5000 RPM it kind of puts the brakes on so I change to 2nd and accelerate hard again but the same thing happens when I reach the same revs, so into third but the revs never seem to get up that high so I keep accelerating & changing up the gears.
Any ideas?
I've told mini garage about this problem but I think they don't want to know about it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell me who makes the "Mini Coupe" ... I've not heard of it before.

Comment: BMW now, used to be British Leyland... if it's the Mini I know... But twin turbo? Well, i know there was a supercharged mini but that was looooong ago... Original mini was designed by Sir Alex Issigonis...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_Coup%C3%A9_and_Roadster

Comment: @SolarMike -  Oh, so he's asking about a MINI Cooper Coupe? Sorry, I was not trying to guess at what he's talking about, especially since I don't remember the MINI Cooper coming as a twin turbo from the factory. Can you even fit a twin turbo in a MINI?

Comment: Perhaps the "twin turbo" is a misnomer: most seem to refer to it as a "twin scroll turbo"...

Comment: The BMW N18 engine for the mini, and the later B48 engine, were both twin scroll turbos.

Comment: @alephzero - Twin scroll does not equal twin turbo. And maybe Mike is correct on this. I'm just trying to clarify without assuming.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes I know the difference, I was just trying to clarify that some of the standard engine range for the mini were twin scroll (but none were twin turbo AFAIK).